# NextLink is 1 step behind

Tags: next.js, next-link

So this is my component state:

```
export default function DateNavigator() { 
  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date());
  const urlDate = formatToDateOnlyISO(currentDate);
  console.log(urlDate) // 2023-11-25
  
  return (
    <Link href={`?date=${urlDate}`} onClick={goToPrevDate}>
          ...
    </Link>
  )

}
```

and url is `http://localhost:3000/top-trends`

now when user goes back or previous, day is incremented with one but url is 1 step behind, so if today is:

`2023-11-25` and user press back, date is correctly updated to `2023-11-24`, however then query param in the url is displayed as `2023-11-25` so is always 1 step behind, any idea how to synchronize it